# Does the German Wiktionary have a way to request words to be added?

Tags: wiktionary

I'm a long time contributor to the English Wiktionary but I'd like to request an entry for a word current not in the Germany Wiktionary for the first time.

For those not aware, while all Wiktionaries run on the same MediaWiki software, content-wise they all evolved separately so things such as entry formats, category structures, templates, and pages that implement certain features are all totally different.

To ask for a German word to be added on the English Wiktionary [I can add a request to this page](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary%3aRequested_entries_%28German%29). But I don't know if the Germany Wiktionary has a way be it the same or totally different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The wishlist for adding a request for a German word in the German Wiktionary seems to be http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Wunschliste.

If you are looking for the German Wiktionary to add a word in English or other foreign language, the correct page is http://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wiktionary:Wunschliste/Fremdsprachen.